# importing an array into a class and cycling through using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, class, sorting, constructor

```
<?php
$arr=array("b"=>4,"a"=>2,"c"=>8,"d"=>"6");

class Sort {

    public $arr = array(); 

    public function __construct(&$arr=array()) {
        $this->arr = $arr;
    }

    static function my_sort($a,$b) {
        //I am trying to cycle through the array $arr within this class
        foreach ($this->arr as $key => $value) { 
            print "success";
        }

        if ($a==$b) 
            return 0;

        return ($a<$b)?-1:1;
    }

}

uasort($arr,array("Sort","my_sort")); 
print_r($arr);
?>
```

I would like to cycle through the array $arr using foreach, while also within the sorting function my_sort, but I can't figure out how to properly reference the array. I set up a public constructor which references the array, but I'm unsure of how to interact with the array after it's been initialized.

Comment: Tidied the code.... much easier to read now

Comment: Well what is the problem? Any errors? Something..?

Comment: _Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context_

Answer (score 0):

imo there is 2 problems :

- "importing" the array into you class: what you did is ok

```php
$arr = array("b"=>4,"a"=>2,"c"=>8,"d"=>"6");
$sort = new Sort($arr);
```

Your array is now referenced in you class

- sorting you array: add a sort() function to your class

```php
public function sort()
{
    return uasort($this->arr, array(__CLASS__, "my_sort"));
}
```

Use the function

```php
$sort->sort();
```

PS: your my_sort function is wrong, it should not contain $this. Use another non static function to walk throw the array.

You can modify the sort() function ie:

```php
public function sort()
{
    foreach ($this->arr as $item) {
        //stuff
    }
    return uasort($this->arr, array(__CLASS__, "my_sort"));
}
```